# kafka producer unit test (java)

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

Doing my first steps with kafka (java code) I would like to create a simple test for kafka producer, something like [this](https://gist.github.com/asmaier/6465468) where I can mock zoo keeper (this implementation looks nice but I can't reach some of the classes there, specifically EmbeddedZookeeper and TestUtils).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the Kafka-test artifact:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.9.2</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.0</version>
    <classifier>test</classifier>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you need a separate mock for zookeeper, Apache curator-test might do:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
    <version>2.3.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <artifactId>curator-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is worth to mention that, in order to take the most of Kafka's test artifact when testing a producer, you might want to take a look at this snippet: https://gist.github.com/asmaier/6465468

Comment: in case of kafka 8 - this is the accepted answer, but I think this should not work for kafka 7.x

Answer (score 1):

Probably taken from the Kafka source .. 
Check [here](https://github.com/kafka-dev/kafka/blob/b1e2d544d4e81571bbfe59defa62d5f7a674c9e0/core/src/test/scala/unit/kafka/zk/EmbeddedZookeeper.scala) for EmbeddedZk  and [here](https://github.com/kafka-dev/kafka/blob/b1e2d544d4e81571bbfe59defa62d5f7a674c9e0/core/src/test/scala/unit/kafka/utils/TestUtils.scala) for the Utils ..

The full package is available [here](https://github.com/kafka-dev/kafka/tree/b1e2d544d4e81571bbfe59defa62d5f7a674c9e0/core/src/test/scala/unit/kafka)

see if it helps

Comment: Thanks. This is scala, I'm using java. I know both can run on my jvm but for this to happen I need the jar that contains those classes, isn't so? How else can I use it in my java code?

Comment: Other way could be configure scala projects and then you can use them in your java classes (as it is possible to call methods from either languages). The example you are looking at probably using the scala base, however I am not sure how exactly it is implemented.m also looking for the same issue, will keep you posted

Comment: Don't use kafka-dev repository -- it is outdated and isn't maintained for a looong time -- rely on https://github.com/apache/kafka which is up to date and quite official mirror.

Comment: @om-nom-nom What should I add to my pom for this?

Comment: @forhas kafka test utils lies under test root -- this means they won't go to the result artifact and you have to copy source if you want to use them.